# load balancing using tomcat

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, load-balancing

I want to balance the load of web application between **two tomcat server installed on two different machines**(not in same machine).what will be the best idea to configure the load balancing? How to make such configuration ?

Comment: Apache mod_jk using [sticky sessions](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html) [On Ubuntu](http://blog.cwill-dev.com/2011/04/07/installing-apache2-and-tomcat6-with-mod_jk-on-ubuntu-10-10/) [Another Linux guide](http://anujjaiswal.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/configuring-mod_jk-tomcat-7-0-and-apache-2-2/) JBoss has a nice [guide](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r4/html/cluster.chapt.html) Either Windows or Linux it's easy to setup and quite similar

Comment: currently its on linux after word it may be on windows

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855841/load-balance-web-application

Comment: @Alex thanx for providing more answers

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions that all helped me. I found another good links which are as follow: [http://hosteddocs.ittoolbox.com/AP121907.pdf](http://hosteddocs.ittoolbox.com/AP121907.pdf) [http://raibledesigns.com/tomcat/](http://raibledesigns.com/tomcat/)

Answer (score 4):

Based on my humble experience: [Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/) with [mod_proxy_balancer](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html) has being used as a machine for load balancing (for small number of servers, e.g. 3-5) - and it proved to be a good choice.